# Checking only the O_RDONLY flag to open(2)

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, bitwise-operators

I'm checking the flags sent to the open(2) call against permissions I've set up in some meta files. The perms here are related to the octal values typically sent to calls like chmod. I want the if block to be entered when perms is not matched by the relevant flag.

```
if((perms == 4 && !(flags & O_RDONLY)) ||
   (perms == 2 && !(flags & O_WRONLY)) ||
   (perms == 6 && !(flags & O_RDWR)))
```

I expected this to work, and it does just fine in the the O_WRONLY and O_RDWR. However, the actual value of O_RDONLY is 0, so the & operator will return false for every value. Unfortunately, removing the negation will lead to the undesired behavior of every perms value of 4 skipping the if block. How can I achieve my goal here?

Comment: Use `((flags&O_ACCMODE)==O_RDONLY)`, etc.

Comment: While the `flags` argument can contain flags, the open modes themselves are *not* flags.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg flags here is equal to the open system argument `int flags`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, the second argument to [open](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man2/open.2) was called *mode* and was documented as being 0, 1, or 2. [Later on](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=SysIII/usr/src/man/man2/open.2), the argument was renamed *oflag*, and it could now contain flags in addition to the access mode. The possible values for the mode were kept the same, though, and symbolic names were given for them, with the caution that, unlike flags, only one of `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_RDWR` could be used. The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/fcntl.h.html) includes the following definition:

> Mask for use with file access modes is as follows:
>   
>      `O_ACCMODE`  Mask for file access modes.

So you can use code such as `((flags&O_ACCMODE) == O_RDONLY)`, etc.

Comment: So if `((flags&O_ACCMODE) == O_RDONLY` evaluated to true,  `((flags&O_ACCMODE) == O_RDWR` could not evaluate to true, correct? I'm running into instances of a mode evaluating to 644 where the current user is the owner, but an strace reveals that the files are being opened using O_RDONLY.


I thought I'd just add extra logic so that when a value of 6 was found for perms it also checks RDONLY and WRONLY but that seems not only lazy but like it could be troublesome.

Comment: Yes, if (flags&O_ACCMODE) == O_RDONLY, then (flags&O_ACCMODE) will not == O_RDWR. If you need to compare these more than once, it may be worth converting the access mode into a value where you can test single bits denoting read or write access. The UNIX kernel does this - long ago, it would take the mode argument (presumably 0, 1, or 2) and simply add 1 to it, then look at the low 2 bits of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
int open_mode = (flags & O_ACCMODE);
```

Then you can use checks like:

```
(open_mode == O_RDONLY)
```